# Find a value in a tree

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, recursion, data-structures

I need to create a method that checks if a given integer is present in the tree or not and respectively return true or false.
The tree is not a binary search tree therefore the values of the node are not always smaller on the left.
My constructor is as below:

```
public class TreeNode {
    TreeNode left; 
    int payload; 
    TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(int x){
       payload = x; 
    }
```

The below method work perfectly:

```
public boolean find(int x,TreeNode root) {

    if (root.payload == x) {
        return true;
    } if (root.left != null && find(x, root.left)){
        return true;
    }if (root.right != null && find(x, root.right)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

However I realised i need to follow the guide and do it as follow:

```
 public Boolean find(int x)
```

How can I change my code to implement this version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this an instance method by replacing passing a tree to invoke method on with `this`:

```
public Boolean find(int x) {

    if (this.payload == x) {
        return true;
    } if (this.left != null && this.left.find(x)){
        return true;
    }if (this.right != null && this.right.find(x)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: It gives an error:  remove argument to match find(int).

Comment: As the method takes only 1 argument it says to remove one or add one and match (int, TreeNode)